# Why would the entropy of a domain wall outweigh the energetic costs?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, entropy, field-theory, phase-transition

I'm reading through David Tong's notes on statistical field theory and on page 29, it is stated that the probability of having a domain wall anywhere on an interval from $x=-L/2$ to $x=L/2$ returns:

$p[\text{wall anywhere}] = \frac{e^{-\beta F_{wall}}}{Z}\frac{L}{W}$

The context is that we fixed magnetisation to be at $m=m_0$, the positive ground state, at $x=-L/2$. Tong states that for a large enough system, the factor of $L/W$ will overwhelm any exponential suppression and that this is an example of the entropy of a configuration - which in this case is $\text{log}(L/W)$ outweighing the energetic cost.

I'm curious why $\text{log}(L/W)$ is considered the entropy in this case. My intuition says that the $L/W$ is a rough approximation of the number of states the system can have with a single domain wall. Please let me know if this is the right idea or if there's some other explanation.